# executeFetchRequest taking too long .

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchrequest

Even though I don't have more than 3 records in my table , and a single table. Method : executeFetchRequest takes too long

```
loanIDArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
appDelegate=[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
context=[appDelegate managedObjectContext];
entityDesc=[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Personal_Info" inManagedObjectContext:context];

NSFetchRequest* request=[[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
[request setEntity:entityDesc];
NSPredicate* predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"status_of_form==%@",@"Completed"];
[request setPredicate:predicate];

NSError* fetchError;
NSError* error;
```

This line takes too long

```
NSArray* objects = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&fetchError];

if (!fetchError) {
    for (NSManagedObject* obj in objects) {
        [loanIDArray addObject:[obj valueForKey:@"app_id"]];

    }
}
else
    NSLog(@"Status Fetch Error : %@",fetchError.description);

[context save:&error];

if (!error)
    NSLog(@"count : %d",loanIDArray.count );
else
    NSLog(@"error : %@",error.description);
```

Comment: Please describe your `Personal_Info` entity structure (how many attributes and of what type), also, what is "too long" (seconds,milliseconds)? a fetch request execution is a disk access so anywhere between 10-100[ms] on a device is reasonable (depending on the nature of the application).

Comment: no relationships,.,25 attributes (strings and integer)
but in five attribuutes i store base 64 image format

Comment: depending on the size of the images, this could greatly increase the time it takes CoreData to marshal the data to you object (hence a longer loading time). my advice is you either store the images on disk and store the path as string, or create an `Image` entity with a relationship to the object so the image will not be loadded along with the item on fetch.

Answer (score 0):

try replace this code:

```
if (!fetchError) {
    for (NSManagedObject* obj in objects) {
        [loanIDArray addObject:[obj valueForKey:@"app_id"]];

    }
}
```

with this to avoid iteration:

```
if (!fetchError) {
    loanIDArray = [objects valueForKeyPath:@"app_id"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entityDesc];

NSError *error = nil;
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"status_of_form==%@",@"Completed"];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
NSArray *request = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
if (!request.count==0) {
    for (int i = 0; i<=request.count-1;i++) {
        NSManagedObject *obj = [request objectAtIndex:i];
        [loanIDArray addObject:[obj valueForKey:@"app_id"]];
    }
}
```

Comment: NSArray* objects = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&fetchError];

This is the line which is taking time,.,the for loop is working fine

Comment: How long is it exactly taking ? And what attributes does that NSManagedObject handles? Is there any relationships one to many ?

Comment: It takes few second,.,
and structure of Personal_Info -no relationships,.,25 attributes (strings and integer) but in five attribuutes i store base 64 image format

Comment: Then that's the reason, your object contains a bunch of attributes, It is normal for an object that size, you could however try to re-structure your object in a more "functionality oriented" way, try to convert your current object into different ones and tie them with relationships according to your needs.